# Possible thread issue?

Tags: java, swt, refresh, tableviewer

I have 2 classes, one class is a datamodel class and the other is a gui class.

class datamodel .........

Takes user selected data and creates a arraylist

class gui .........

Has a tableviewer that is using the array from the datamodel class

My issue is I need to fresh the tableviewer when the user has added more data to the array.

I created a updateTableViewer method in the gui class.

```
public void updateTableViewer() {
  if(getViewer() != null) {
     viewer.refresh();
 {
```

Then I made a reference to the gui class in the datamodel class.

```
AplotBaseDialog abd = new AplotBaseDialog(null, null);
```

Then I added the method call to the method adding more data to the array

```
public void add(TCComponentItemRevision tcRevision, TCComponentDataset selectedDataset) {
  AplotDatasetData pp = new AplotDatasetData(tcRevision, selectedDataset);
  if (!dataArrayList.contains(pp)) {
     dataArrayList.add(pp);
  }
  abd.updateTableViewer();

}// end add()
```

This does not work.  The getViewer() call always returns null, even if the gui class is created and open.

So I create a boolean value;

```
Boolean hasViewerBeenCreated = false;
```

I am setting the value to true after the tableviewer is created.

```
viewer = new AplotDataTableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
  viewer.setInput(AplotDataModel.getInstance().getArrayData());
  hasViewerBeenCreated = true;
```

Then I created a method to return the boolean value.

I am calling the method from a button on the dailog. 
I also replaced the updateTableViewer method call in the datamodel class

```
if (!dataArrayList.contains(pp)) {
     dataArrayList.add(pp);
  }
  abd.getBooleanValue();
}
```

Here are the results.

I execute the add method in the datamodel class - 
It returns false - That makes sense because the dailog has not been created at this time

I execute and create the gui class
I click the button and it returns true - This makes sense because the viewer has been created

Here is where I get confused.
With the gui still open, I can execute the add method again and it stills returns a false value. Then I can click the button and see it is true value.

I would think that when the gui is created and the boolean value is set to true.  I would be able to get the current value of the boolean in other classes.

I am not sure if I am not referencing the gui class correctly or when the gui is created I am not accessing the current thread or tableviewer?

I don't know if this is a thread issue or I am just not getting the current value from the gui correctly.

This is a big issue with my application right now.  I have to be able to refresh the tableviewer any time new data is added to the array. I can not have the user having to manually refresh the table every time that select new data

Comment: Where is "getViewer" method declared and what is it doing? I strongly suspect that you have some field obscured by a local variable with a same name so it is always null.

Comment: getViewer is in the gui class, it only returns null when executed from the singleton class.  It works correctly when executed from the gui class.

Comment: I set the method getViewer to static and that worked for my issue above.

Comment: Without seeing the getViewer code it is impossible to understand why it returns null. Have you debugged the init code to see why the viewer is not created?